# Bluetooth permission not working in android 11 in react native

Tags: android, react-native

My build tool version - 30.0.2
android sdk version 7.0.4
react native version - 68.0

Bluetooth permission is working on android 12 but its not working on 11 or older device.
permission popup not apprears.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Have you taken into account that the [Bluetooth permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions) system has changed from [Android 11](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare-android11-or-lower) to [Android 12](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare-android12-or-higher)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also have this issue and I am working on android 10. I have tested this with android 12 and the bluetooth prompt is working fine. However, the prompt is not showing in android 10 and from your question it also happening for android 11. From my research, I found out that, like @Risto mentioned in your comment, android bluetooth permission system has changed from Android 12. That means the prompt will only show in android 12 or higher.

The problem which I am currently facing is that I want my application to run in android 10 and higher. But if i prompt the bluetooth permission using react native permissionAndroid it won't show in android 10 and if I try to customise it for android 10(in this case we don't need to prompt bluetooth permission, we only need to write permission in android manifest file) the application in android 12 or higher will crash.

So what I am going to do to solve this problem is that I now know that android 12 or higher needs the bluetooth prompt.Using below code we can get the android version

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const Version = Platform.constants['Release'];
```

Using this we can give bluetooth permission prompt in android 12 or higher or not giving any prompt in case android 11 or lower.

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).